# PayPal Smart Subscribe server side

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

hello im trying to convert my PayPal smart subscription button javascript into the server-side particularly on PHP. But I keep looking online and PayPal documentation still can't find and sources. It is similar to [this PayPal demo of server-side](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server).

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Subscription_id&vault=true" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
    <script>
      paypal.Buttons({
          style: {
              shape: 'rect',
              color: 'gold',
              layout: 'horizontal',
              label: 'subscribe'
          },
          createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
              'plan_id': 'Plan_id'
            });
          },
          onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            alert(data.subscriptionID);
          }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a demo sample, but the `createSubscription` portion can be be done via this API call: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create

For subscriptions, by default the subscription will be activated automatically on approval, *before* `onApprove` is called.

You can set the application_context -> user_action to something other than SUBSCRIBE_NOW if you want to show a review step and activate with an API call.