# How do you check a PayPal subscription with the JavaScript SDK?

Tags: paypal

I was able to create a subscription button with the code below:

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=client_id&vault=true" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'subscribe'
      },
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
          'plan_id': 'P-xxxx'
        });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);
        console.log(data); 
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

I was able to test it and it worked fine once I figured out that to test it you have to create a sandbox app at https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/ and use that for the client_id and then login with the sandbox facilitator account at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com and create a sandbox paypal subscription button by going to Pay & Get Paid > Subscriptions > Subscription Plans or https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans and "Create Plan" and use that for the plan_id.

After I tested the subscription button by purchasing it with the sandbox buyer account I was then able to check the status of the subscription online at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/subscriptions using the sandbox facilitator account.

But I do not see a way to check the status of a subscription using the subscription ID and the JavaScript SDK. How do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript SDK is for the web approval, not for things like checking the status.

For this you use the Subscriptions API. Here's the overview documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/

In particular you want to get the details of a subscription: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/full-integration/subscription-management/#show-subscription-details

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-######### \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>"
```

---

Since you'll be using server code for such a check anyway, you may be interested in [a server implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63899329/paypal-smart-subscribe-server-side/63908112#63908112) which is more robust, since you are immediately informed on the server side of when a subscription becomes active.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does appear that there is not a way to get the status with the JavaScript SDK. Even after chatting wtih PayPal support. I did figure out how to check with PHP. It is too bad though because this is for a Chrome Extension. It is a waste to have to contact 2 servers to get the status of a subscription.