# PayPal Payment Definition: Trial & Regular

Tags: php, paypal

As some may have noticed PayPal's SDK documentation can be quite poor to say the least, creating issues for developers.

My current is is regarding the Billing Plan `payment_definitions`.

I have developed a discount feature which will in return give a discount for a specified amount to the user. I wish for this discount to be applied only for first month. The poor documentation regarding the billing plan is confusing me when it comes to creating the payment definition object. Is it possible to have both a trial and a regular payment definition defined?

See below code for my example of what I am working with at the moment.

```
        if(Wo_DiscountAvailable($discount)){
            // (total-(total/100*percentage))
            $dc_total = ($total-(Wo_DiscountPercentage($discount)/100*$total));
            $tDefinition = new \PayPal\Api\PaymentDefinition();
            $tDefinition->setName('Regular Payments user' . $wo['user']['id'])->setType('TRIAL')
                ->setFrequency($p_type)->setFrequencyInterval('1')
                ->setCycles('1')
                ->setAmount(new \PayPal\Api\Currency(array(
                'value' => $dc_total,
                'currency' => $wo['config']['paypal_currency']
            )));     
            $paymentDefinition = new \PayPal\Api\PaymentDefinition();
            $paymentDefinition->setName('Regular Payments user' . $wo['user']['id'])->setType('REGULAR')
                ->setFrequency($p_type)->setFrequencyInterval('1')
                ->setCycles('47')
                ->setAmount(new \PayPal\Api\Currency(array(
                'value' => $total,
                'currency' => $wo['config']['paypal_currency']
            )));       
        } else {
            // Set billing plan definitions
            $paymentDefinition = new \PayPal\Api\PaymentDefinition();
            $paymentDefinition->setName('Regular Payments user' . $wo['user']['id'])->setType('REGULAR')
                ->setFrequency($p_type)->setFrequencyInterval('1')
                ->setCycles('48')
                ->setAmount(new \PayPal\Api\Currency(array(
                'value' => $total,
                'currency' => $wo['config']['paypal_currency']
            )));
        }

        if(Wo_DiscountAvailable($discount)){
            $plan->setPaymentDefinitions(array(
                $tDefinition, $paymentDefinition
            ));
        } else {
            $plan->setPaymentDefinitions(array(
                $paymentDefinition
            ));
        }
```

Above include functions Wo_DiscountAvailable and Wo_DiscountPercentage - these both work

The former function returns true or false if it is available for use and discount returns value of discount.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) as seems to be the case, stop doing that. It is [deprecated](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/deprecated-rest-sdks/), and its use of billing plans is not compatible with the [Subscriptions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/), if that is what you are looking to integrate.

There is no SDK for the current Subscriptions API; use direct HTTPS calls with for example PHP's curl if you are doing a server-based integration.

If you want a Smart Subscribe button to call your server for the createSubscription and for activation so you can save a record of it in your database, here is a guide for that: [PayPal Smart Subscribe server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63899329/paypal-smart-subscribe-server-side/63908112#63908112)