# How to integrate Paypal smart button into vue browser extension pwa

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, paypal, progressive-web-apps

While I was looking for a way to integrate payment and subscriptions to my existing vue projects, I've found the Paypal smart buttons documentations. It's seems a secure solution to use in client solutions, anyone tried it with vue? I will use the sdk into my vue browser extension because to replace the CWS deprecated API, so I'm worried about security aspect. It's not clear if I need also server side code to use the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe buttons are client-side, unless you [pair one with a server integration.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63908112/2069605)

You can [generate subscribe buttons at PayPal.](https://www.paypal.com/billing/subscription-button-editor)

Comment: whitch solution is the best? I see that smart buttons are more flexible than button generated?

Comment: One requires a server, the other doesn't. Doing things with a server is useful if you need to have an immediate, server-side record of newly created subscriptions IDs.

Comment: It can be also integrated with firebase or firestore for the server side part?

Comment: Those are databases as far as I know. You need a programming environment that can execute API calls and a place to create your own API endpoints.