# Simple Paypal Button Subscription Membership

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm new here!

I'm trying to let my customers get recuring billing membership on my website based on [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/paypal-integration-part-1-paypal-payment-buttons--cms-22916).

The button work, evverything is fine, except one thing. I need to validate that paypal really went successfull, to prevent anyone to go directly on the success page and get free membership. I noticed that it return a token=VALUE data to the success / cancel redirect.

I cannot find any $_POST or any others $_GET than that and I wonder, nor anything that could solve this in the Paypal doc (which changed a lot since last time I used it).

How can I check if the membership really went trought paypal using this token=1RXXXXXXXXH484112Y.

Answer (score 0):

The return of such an integration may never happen. Reliable notification that a subscription has been created can only be done with a separate, server-side integration.

For the old HTML subscription button integration in the tutorial you reference, you can implement the old Instant Payment Notification (IPN) service.

---

The current solution would be to use a smart subscribe button with server side API calls to create the subscription and activate it -- with this, your server immediately knows it has been activated (because it did so itself and received the response). You can find some details on that solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63908112/2069605