# How to implement payments in chrome extension

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-firestore, paypal, slim

I have a slim 4 app that will use the JWT token provided from firebase auth on the client side to authorize the users to make ajax calls to certain endpoints.

The client side app is a chrome extension powered by vue.js and will rely on authentication to display the views and to give to the user the ability to use it's functionality.

What I want to do is to add a paypal subscription button (paypal smart buttons?) to give to the users the ability to pay a fee and unlock some features that are managed from the server. Since I didn't ever implemented something similar in a chorme extension, I need to understand what is the correct flow to manage free/paid users. I'm thinking to use firestore to track the paying users but I'm not sure if I need to implement the check on the client side or on server side that is hosted by heroku. After the user click on the subscription button that I want to implement in the option page of the extension, how I will comunicate with server or with firestore to save the transation informations?Maybe there is a best payment service I can implement to manage this?

I've done a lot of researh but I'm not able to find any code example about this particular topic, every help to take the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For PayPal you can use API calls to [activate a subscription from a server.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63899329/paypal-smart-subscribe-server-side/63908112#63908112)

This gives you reliable server-side notification that a subscription is started.

To be notified of actual payment transactions on the subscription, which typically **start the following day** and repeat on its cycle, you need a webhook listener for the event [PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions)

Comment: But what do you do on the frontend to accept user details (such as credit card information) securely given that you cannot use PayPal smart buttons under Manifest V3, since those rely on an external script?

Comment: The most straightforward way is to host the subscription/checkout button on your own site's page.

Comment: Right, but it's a shame that I have to run a website in order to offer an extension.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to use the [ExtensionPay](https://extensionpay.com) service which gives you a simple API to take payments in your extension.

Comment: It's a new service?

Comment: Yep! Came out a little before the Chrome Store shut down their payment system.

Comment: I've seen the link, I will take a look at stripe as I've understand the library works with only with stripe at the moment. I'm not sure about implementation but in the extension I want to implement it, the main functions are done on server so I think I need also to have a database to track users. Thanks for the help