# PayPal: After Check whether subscriber is paid for subscription

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, paypal-sandbox

I'm creating website using reactjs for frontend and for backend I'm using c# asp .net mvc. I have already integrated paypal subscription in whichevery month fixed amount deducted form his account(which I have already done) by following this link https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/paypal-subscription-in-react-1121c39b26be. and here is my code.

```
window.paypal.Buttons({
            style: {
                shape: 'rect',
                color: 'gold',
                layout: 'vertical',
                label: 'subscribe'
            },
            createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
              return actions.subscription.create({
                'plan_id': 'my-plan-id'
              });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
              alert(data.subscriptionID);
              console.log(data)
            },
            onError: (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }).render(paypal.current)
```

but my requirement is when user login first time user must provide his paypal account details and after providing paypal account info check user has sufficient amount in his account proceed to dashboard. But my problem is how to handle if user has no balance in his account or unpaid and in this case after login user redirected to specific page not dashboard.

In short: how to check user is paid or unpaid if paid proceed to dashboard else redirect to specific page.

Answer (score 1):

> how to check user is paid or unpaid if paid proceed to dashboard else redirect to specific page.

The answer to this is to consult your database, which should have this information stored (whether a payment has been made, or whether the subscription is current) and allow you to determine what to do based on the information you have.

So your real question must be how to receive notifications from PayPal that a subscription payment has been made. For that, I will refer you to the answer in here: [How do you know if a user has paid for a subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65138364/how-do-you-know-if-a-user-has-paid-for-a-subscription/65139331#65139331)

As for how to match subscription payments to users -- when a subscription is created, you can store its ID associated with your user, which is easiest to do if you activate the subscription from the server as discussed above.  You can also pass a `custom_id` field during subscription creation, which can contain your own user ID for reconciliation.