# How to create RestAPI for paypal reccuring payment?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, payment

I'm currently working with a recurring PayPal payment. I'm not sure to understand when the first payment is done. In my case, I want to first payment to be done when the user subscribes and automatically renew after 1 month.

Here is my RestAPI code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\WSController;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\PaymentPlans;
use App\Models\Subscription;
use App\Models\Users;
use Auth;
use DB;
use Hash;
use Session;
use Stripe;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

class WSPaypalTestController extends Controller
{
    public function paypalpaymenttest()
    {
        global $environment;
        $paymentAmount = urlencode('105.87');
        $currencyID = urlencode('USD');                         
        $paymentType = urlencode('Authorization');           
        $returnURL = "http://localhost/paypal/new/success.php"; 
        $cancelURL = 'http://localhost/paypal/new/cencel.php'; 

        $paypal_data = [
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => $currencyID,
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'SALE',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC' => 'Hosted Saas Tier 1 and Community Management Services',
            'PAYMENTACTION' => $paymentType,
            'L_BILLINGTYPE0' => 'RecurringPayments',
            'L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0' => 'Description of Community Management Services',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0'      => 'Community Management Services 8 hours for $0.01',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0'    => '010101',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0'       => '1',
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'       => $paymentAmount,
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'      => $paymentAmount,
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'          => $paymentAmount
        ];

        $nvpStr = http_build_query($paypal_data);
        $methodName_ = 'doExpressChechoutPayment';

        $API_UserName = urlencode('');
        $API_Password = urlencode('');
        $API_Signature = urlencode('');

        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";

        if ("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {    
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";

        }

        $version = urlencode('124.0');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     

        $nvpreq="METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature&$nvpStr";   

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);
        $httpResponse =curl_exec($ch);

        if (!$httpResponse) {
            exit("$methodName_ failed:".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
        }

        $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);
        $httpParsedResponseAr = array();

        foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) { 
            $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);  
            if (sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {   
                $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];   
            }   
        }
    
        if ((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
            exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't have any issue but why not use a object oriented guzzle instead of curl if you are using laravel which uses object oriented concepts

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not for the REST API, that is the old classic NVP API you are attempting to use. Super old, and not compatible with the current version of [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) which is at least a couple generations newer. You should most definitely integrate the latest version.

Here's an answer on how to use the current version of PayPal Subscriptions: [How do you know if a user has paid for a subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65138364/how-do-you-know-if-a-user-has-paid-for-a-subscription/65139331#65139331)

In particular, the last sentence seems relevant to your question here:

> If you need to receive a payment the moment a subscription starts (instead of the following day), configure it with a `setup_fee` and a one cycle trial period before the regular billing cycle begins.