# Create subscription system for PayPal course

Tags: node.js, paypal

I am trying to create a subscription system with PayPal for a user subscribe to a course. So far I have already made the billing agreement and this has no problems, but the problem is that I want each month or each time the subscription is paid, the user is automatically reenrolled, otherwise if it is not possible to charge (maximum 2 attempts) the subscription is canceled and they no longer have access to the course. This last part I have no idea how I could do it, basically I don't know how I can check the status of the agreement and cancel when it is not paid.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/subscriptions/) does not use "billing agreements". If you have integrated with billing agreements, that is the previous version of PayPal Subscriptions and you should discard that deprecated implementation and read the current documentation, which only uses: Products, Plans, and Subscriptions.

(Do not use Billing Agreements, and do not use the deprecated [PayPal-Node-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK). Use the Subscriptions API directly)

To receive notifications of when a Subscription is paid for or its status otherwise changes, [integrate Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions).

---

Some other possibly useful information: [How do you know if a user has paid for a subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65138364/how-do-you-know-if-a-user-has-paid-for-a-subscription)