# Paypal Smartbuttons | How to keep the onApprove hidden

Tags: javascript, paypal

Good day,

For my website I am trying to create a membership with the paypal smart buttons. Here is my script:

```
      <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=#######&vault=true&intent=subscription" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
      <script>
          paypal.Buttons({
              style: {
                  shape: 'pill',
                  color: 'black',
                  layout: 'vertical',
                  label: 'subscribe',
                  size: 'responsive',
              },
              createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
                  return actions.subscription.create({
                      'plan_id': 'P-######'
                  });
              },
              onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                  window.location.href='#Goto somewhere#?p=successfull';
              }
          }).render('#paypal-button-container');
          </script>
```

The point is that everyone could see where to go for the next step but I would rather that they could not, since that url gives a parameter that will update someone's rank. Is there a possibility to keep it hidden or visually change it?

Comment: Can you clarify if you re trying to hide the code, the url parameter or the page.  This code is client side so anyone that knows how to use dev tools can look at it.

Comment: There is no way to physically hide the code unless you put it on your server (or use some obfuscation software).  If you have access to where you are hosting your site, you could perform the redirect server-side and could hide any number of variable and conditions there.

Comment: @VladimirMujakovic How could I hide numbers on the server side?

Comment: in your `onApprove` callback, you could fire off an AJAX function that performs the logic of your redirect.  So instead of writing window.location.href= ... you would call a function that makes a request to your server which would then perform your redirect with any number of parameters.

Comment: I am happy to mock up such a function if it is useful.

Comment: For a more extensive treatment of verifying that a user has paid for a PayPal subscription, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65138364/how-do-you-know-if-a-user-has-paid-for-a-subscription

Comment: @VladimirMujakovic Yes please, Also please make it as a anwser please so if it works I can accept it :)