# Check if user have valid subscription on PayPal

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, subscription, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

In our app user is paying for one year of use during checkout and then after a year we are staring to charge subscription.

Let's say that users are identified by email. So, how can I verify that user have now an active subscription ?

I have seen a few [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65138364/how-do-you-know-if-a-user-has-paid-for-a-subscription/65139331#65139331) that suggest to build webhook and listen to PayPal events.
In our flow the initial purchase will be on WordPress website with one of the subscriptions Plugins and then I need to "activate" subscription in the App.

Is the "webhook" the only possible option with PayPal?
I have seen something in Braintree SDK related to subscription, can this work?

Seems to me too complicated to build the whole system only to verify subscription. In Stripe, for example, you can proactively ask if the user has subscription.

Answer (score 0):

The webhook PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED informs of every completed subscription payment. Use this information to continuously update your records of whether a user has a paid-for subscription.

If you need metadata for reconciliation of which subscription corresponds to which user (since however they are identified at PayPal may not correspond to however you identify them), you can set the parameter `custom_id` when creating the subscription, to any value of up to 127 characters.

If you need to download a transaction history of previous payments, you can get a report in CSV format from the https://www.paypal.com account interface, typically under Activity -> All Reports -> Activity Download. This can then be imported to a database to backfill any gap in your records that you don't have webhook events for.

Comment: Thanks for reply!
In PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED data do I have some id that will help me connect it to subscription?
I have seen also the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65138364/how-do-you-know-if-a-user-has-paid-for-a-subscription)
Inside BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED event I have "email_address": "customer@example.com"
So, maybe I can use it to identify users without custom_id?

Comment: There may be an email address returned, or there may not, but more importantly there's no reason an email used at PayPal will correspond to whatever email you have a record of so using it is dubious

Comment: And will I receive custom_id as part of any PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED event?

Comment: Yes, custom_id is returned

Comment: That make sense. And how can I know that subscription canceled/refunded? I need it to update end date.

Comment: Subscription cancellations only effect future payments, so they are not important to track.  Receiving a PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED already lets you infer how long the current paid-for period is good for. Refund event notifications are PAYMENT.SALE.REFUNDED , useful if the refund took place independently of your system e.g. in www.paypal.com (If your system did the refund via API you already have an immediate response and don't need the webhook)

Comment: In my case all the charges and refunds are done on WordPress site. While the hook and confirmation for subscription are done on Node.js backend. These systems actually are not connected together and not supposed to be connected.
So, listening to PAYMENT.SALE.REFUNDED probably the only option to cancel the subscription on App backend in case of refund. Does it sounds right to you?

Comment: If the systems aren't to be connected, then yes that is the only option to automate one receiving notifications from PayPal of events the other triggered