# PayPal Subscriptions: validating success on a server

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I apologize in advance for this question, as its probably rather silly, but I really can not find any answers elsewhere.

My current goal is to integrate a subscription to my website, that allows for a user to have access to certain parts of the site.

I've watched a few videos on it, but it leaves me open ended with some questions.

PayPal allows you to manually create a subscription plan at https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans. When you create a plan here, it gives you the code you need to get the pay pal sub buttons to display on the page. Users can then use them to create the subscription. This is great. However, I have found now way to validate the results of the transaction. My goal would be that if the user was successful, I would be able to retrieve data via the API, that says it was successful, and I could then store than information in my database, and grant them access. Does anyone know how to get the data from the manually created facebook plans?

I did watch a video that had you do everything from your website (you create it all within your own code), the end result however sent everything through $_GET variables in the url. I feel like having this data exposed could result in the manipulation of the subscription, and grant it to users who were unsuccessful in creating a subscription.

I have no problem doing all of the coding to make this work, but I really want to make sure I do it the best possible way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PayPal Smart Subscribe server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63899329/paypal-smart-subscribe-server-side)

Answer (score 0):

There is a few way to do it. By setting up a [webhook](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/) and listen to paypal success notification and react to it. By using the Paypal Subscription [API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions). Or a combination of both.

As you are using the paypal button you will have the onApprove function which will trigger upon user confirming the subscription. You can query the subscription data with:

```
onApprove={async (data: any, actions: any) => {
      const detailedSubscriptionData = await actions.subscription.get()

      // activate subscription on your side by sending it to your backend
      ...

      // etc.
    }}
```

Inside the data you have queried above, there will be a paypal transaction id (I-....) that is unique for each transaction, as well as your product id (plan_id). You can now do the following for verification on your backend:

1. Check if there is already a subscription (from another customer) on your side with that paypal transaction id
2. Check for the plan_id
3. Queried the API [Subscription Details](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_get) with the paypal transaction id and check for status, etc. as well as matching of plan_id

Keep in mind that for using the API you will have to queried for an [access-token](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/) which in turn required you to have Developer App Setup following these [steps](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-credentials).

Comment: The code you posted in your answer, where is this onApprove? In the javascript code for my button integration there is an onApprove but it is an object. Where would your code be inserted? I have looked at the paypal webhooks and I do not understand any of it right now. I'm still learning about all this API stuff.